# Custom Paperclip processor not being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have a user model that is generated using Devise. I am extending this model using paperclip to enable file upload and also the processing of a file using a custom paperclip processor.

My paperclip field is declared in the user model as follows. PaperClipStorage is a hash that I create with the paperclip variables. Also, the being stored on AWS S3.

```
has_attached_file :rb_resume, PaperclipStorageHash.merge(:style => { :contents => 'resume_contents'}, :processors => [:resume_builder])
validates_attachment_content_type :rb_resume, :if => lambda { |x| x.rb_resume? }, :content_type => ['application/pdf', 'application/x-pdf', 'application/msword', 'application/x-doc']
```

The validates_attachment_content_type check is being done to make sure that it only processes pdf and MS word files.

My processor looks as follows

```
module Paperclip
  class ResumeBuilder < Processor
    def initialize(file,options = {}, attachment = nil)
      @file = file
      @attachment = attachment
      puts "Attachment is not null " if !attachment.nil?
    end

    def make
      rb = MyModule::MyClass.new(@file.path) ### Do something with the file
      section_layout  = rb.parse_html
      @attachment.instance_write(:whiny, section_layout)
      @file
    end
  end
end
```

In my user model I also have an `after_save` callback that is supposed to take the `section_layout` generated in the processors make method. Code is as follows

```
after_save :save_sections
def save_sections
   section_layout = rb_resume.instance_read(:whiny)
   # Do something with section_layout...
end
```

Now my problem is that the processor code is never being called, and I can't figure out why.

Because of that the section_layout variable is always nil.

Another point to note is that the same model also has two other `has_attached_file` attributes. None of the other two use a custom processor.

I've been struggling with this for last 3 hours. Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error in my has_attached_file declaration

```
has_attached_file :rb_resume, PaperclipStorageHash.merge(:style => { :contents => 'resume_contents'}, :processors => [:resume_builder])
```

should actually be

```
has_attached_file :rb_resume, PaperclipStorageHash.merge(:styles => { :contents => 'resume_contents'}, :processors => [:resume_builder])
```

Notice the plural styles as opposed to singular style